# Logins through public role

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2017, system-administration

We are trying to install a release for our application. The program uses 2 SLQ Accounts: SA and SAA2.

SAA2 should be a standard user which can run some Select Statement. SA is a super admin (Captain Obvious).

However we are stuck in 2 different ways:

1) If we grant sysadmin right to SAA2, our scripts could not run because it refers to to the defined schema implemented in login page of the account. As we understood, since it's associated to sysadmin, the default schema change to dbo. 
But, the account can login successfully

If we want to resolve it by this way, we have to implements these workaround :

- Force account to use his own default schema
- Change our scripts with a full name without using schema (not possible)

> Invalid object name ...

2) If we want to use SAA2 as a standard accounts (because script are mainly focus on SELECT), MSSSQL refuse the account to connect. Indeed, if we try to simply login using SQL Credentials, as a sysadmin it works, as a standard user, it wont. (like this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/23952fef-7ad7-4374-b7e9-89476a62adc9/users-unable-to-access-their-database-unless-they-are-given-sysadmin-permission?forum=sqlsecurity)

> Error number 18456, Severity 14, State 1

We just want to find a way to execute our query, as a sysadmin or not.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions, not admin ones. Please ask in dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: How and why does your script "refers to to the defined schema implemented in login page of the account."?   You might fix your problem by not doing this.

Comment: Formatted question and error segments, corrected grammar